# Opentap Could not copy "[name].dll" to "bin\Debug\Dependencies\[Name].dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed

Tags: c#, dll, sdk, build-error

Maybe someone of you can help me by my problem. At first to make clear this problem is a known problem on stackoverflow and I read all the solutions for that problem and tried them out but this do not solved my problem.

---

**Problem:**

> MSB3027: Could not copy
> "C:\Users\SpecificUser.nuget\packages\opentap\9.10.4\build\payload\Dependencies\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.0.2.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"
> to
> "bin\Debug\Dependencies\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.0.2.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll".
> Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

Due to that error I can't build my solution no matter if I build in debug mode or release mode.

---

**Try to Solve**

1. At first I simply tried to clean the project and rebuild it
2. I also tried to clean the solution and rebuild the solution
3. At next I unloaded the project and reloaded it with and without dependencies
4. Than I tried to close VS2019 and reopened the project in combination with the previous parts
5. After that I tried to uncheck "allows NuGet to automatically check for missing packages during
   build in Visual Studio" (Debug -> options)
6. Than I tried to build the project with all combinations of above
7. Than I tried the same but with Clear All NuGet Cache(s)
8. Than I tried to insert a prebuild action

---

```
if exist "$(TargetPath).locked" del "$(TargetPath).locked" 
if not exist "$(TargetPath).locked" move "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetPath).locked"
```

This throw me an error MSB3073 but without an error message and the description says:

> MSB3073: The command "if exist "C:\Users\SpecificUser\source\repos\ProjectName\bin\Debug\ProjectName.dll.locked" del "C:\Users\SpecificUser\source\repos\ProjectName\bin\Debug\ProjectName.dll.locked"

9. Also, I made sure that the output path is clear
10. At next I tried to delete the bin folder and the obj folder.

All tis step have no success.

**Additional Problem**
Sometimes the dependencies would not load. For that I tried to reinstall them or reload the dependencies. Sometimes it works but usually not. Also, some References such as OpenTAP or Microsoft.CSharp has a yellow rectangular inside the symbol
[yellow rectangular at reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjHG8.png)

**Used Recourses**

- [OpenTAP SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OpenTAP.opentapsdkce)
- [OpenTAP lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTAP/)
- [NetStandard lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/)
- [Microsoft.CSharp lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CSharp/)

**Tried Solutions from StackOverflow**

- [Could not copy "obj\Debug{project}.dll" to "bin{project}.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503509/could-not-copy-obj-debug-project-dll-to-bin-project-dll)
- [visual studio 2013 Could not copy "obj\Debug.dll" to "bin\Debug.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730975/visual-studio-2013-could-not-copy-obj-debug-dll-to-bin-debug-dll)
- [Error: Cannot access file bin/Debug/... because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646047/error-cannot-access-file-bin-debug-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-proc)
- [Unable to Copy File "*\bin\debug*.dll" to "bin*.dll" in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037014/unable-to-copy-file-bin-debug-dll-to-bin-dll-in-visual-studio)
- [Error MSB3027: Could not copy "C:\pagefile.sys" to "bin\roslyn\pagefile.sys". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428409/error-msb3027-could-not-copy-c-pagefile-sys-to-bin-roslyn-pagefile-sys-ex/38847917)

---

Maybe someone can help me with my issue \^o^/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for everyone who is interested what is the solution.

The problem with I hade was, that Visual Studio has problems to solve the dependencies. Due to an test I tried to recreate an project on the same path and moved the old project to my desktop. Than to look at the code I opened the old project and after that it worked.

**Solution**

Visual Studio is not able to solve the dependencies when the path is to long. Now I have changed the path and it works.